How can I import file w=in complex file structure?
I have the following project structure:
.src
    .FolderA
        .File3.js
    .FolderB
        .File2.js
    .File1.js

How can I import File1.js from File3.js?
I have tried import '../src/File1.js'. But its not working

Because ../ lands inside src (considering folders and files does not start with . as in your example), and there is no src folder.
Try ../File1.js
Or add alias to your src folder, e.g.
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}

import ... from '@File1';
import ... from '@FolderA/File3';


